# Adding empty spaces as NULL in a SQL Column in PowerShell SqlBulkCopy

Tags: sql-server, powershell, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I have below code in my PowerShell Script:

```
$bulkcopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy("connection string", ([System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::TableLock, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::KeepNulls)) 
$bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "My Table" 
$bulkcopy.bulkcopyTimeout = 0 
$bulkcopy.batchsize = 50000
```

When I'm calling this:

```
 $bulkcopy.WriteToServer("My DataTable")
```

I have the following problem:

**Exception calling "WriteToServer" with "1" argument(s): "The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type int of the specified target column."**

I think that's because in my external file separate by tabs I have empty values and they are inserted in an integer column but they are not inserted as NULL values instead they are inserted as empty strings "".

How can I solve this?

Comment: By converting the data before you send it over. (Sorry if this sounds too obvious.) Specify the column type explicitly as `[int]` and use `[DBNull]::Value` for nulls.

Comment: Yes I know but I can't do that @JeroenMostert because I use a for by line: while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)  { 
    $value = $line.Split("My delimiter")
    $null = $datatable.Rows.Add($value) and for that I need to make another for for read the columns and the rows and this implies a large increase of time in file reading...

Comment: Depends on whether you have to actually insert empty strings anywhere. If not, you can simply replace all of them with nulls: `$value = $line.Split("delim") |% { if ($_ -eq "") { [DBNull]::Value } else { $_ } };`. Implicit conversions might take care of the rest. Note that this is still a rubbish technique for many types -- relying on implicit conversions of `DateTime` values is a bad idea, as is hoping that the decimal separator is correct.

Comment: Moreover, assuming you do have column names on the first line, there is no large increase in time if you fetch a compatible table definition from the database first (`SELECT TOP(0) * FROM DestinationTable`). This still leaves you with potential conversion issues, but at least you'll know what will have to be converted to what. (And `DataTable` is actually the least efficient way of using `SqlBulkCopy` -- implementing an `IDataReader` that serves up `IDataRecords` requires far less memory. But that's another topic altogether.)

Comment: Thank you for your time and help @JeroenMostert I tried the `$value = $line.Split("delim") |% { if ($_ -eq "") { [DBNull]::Value } else { $_ } };` and works! But the performance is much slower the one I had before this... I will not work with DateTime so it's ok to use this. How can I specify each column with its type? I have this `foreach ($column in $columns) {  
    $null = $datatable.Columns.Add()    
}  `

Comment: `.Add()` has an overload that takes a column name and type. I'm assuming you know the column names since otherwise you couldn't insert into the table in the proper order.

Comment: I'm not understanding one thing. I change the code and now I have `$null = $datatable.Columns.Add("My Column", [int])` but it gave me an error: **"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <200> in "My Int Column" Column.  Expected type is Int32."** in the line `$null = $datatable.Rows.Add($value) ` but if I change the type of all columns to string all works fine, but still takes a lot of time to insert the rows because of `|% { if ($_ -eq "") { [DBNull]::Value } else { $_ } }`. I tried Int32 and gave the same error...

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. I need to cast the value for the type that I want: `|% { if ($_ -eq "") { [DBNull]::Value } else { $_ } }` to **`|% { if ($_ -eq "") { [DBNull]::Value } else { $_ -as [int] } }`** but the performance is very bad too slow... Any ideas to improve? The IDataReader I tried to implement but I has the same error discuted above and to edit the records I have to convert the reader to datatable and then I come back to the starting point.